# How can I get 20 more reputation?

Tags: discussion, comments, reputation

I put a 100 bounty on this question: [Downloading the Panama Papers](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7460/downloading-the-panama-papers)

Unfortunately, I can't comment on the answers given, because I'm now down to 31 reputation (comments require 50). Is it possibly to get a bonus 20 rep, or to be manually given 100rep privileges?

Answer (score 5):

**Easy!** Just add a good answer to some existing questions (10 points per vote)

Or, you can ask another (good) question (5 points per vote).

Answer (score 4):

There is a [discussion on this very topic on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4780/270450). As far I as know, there are currently no mechanisms to manually boost your reputation or grant privileges. But since you only need 20 more points, you should soon regain your commenting privilege anyway.